# Select li classname if it exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

Each time a button is clicked i'm entering a function where I check if a listitem with specific classname exists. If it exists, then it has to be removed.

```
if($("ul#" + this.listClass + " li[class='errorlist']"))
{
    console.log("error");
}
```

Now, it enters the function each time I click, even if it doesn't exist.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you only check for the list item to have a class, doesn't that automatically check whether the list item exists too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for class existing

```
if($('myElement').hasClass('myClassToCheckFor')){
    //do stuff to my element here
}
```

if you want to check for element existing

```
if($('myElement.withMyClass').length > 0) {
    //do stuff to my element here
}
```

So what you want to do is this (this is however not optimized for caching of jquery object but it demonstrates what you need to do).

```
$('button.myButton').click(function(){
    if($('ul li').hasClass('monkey')){
        $('ul li.monkey').remove();
    } else {
        alert("not found!");
    }
});
```

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmTT5/)

Comment: If you just want to remove the li you can do something like :

`if($("ul#" + this.listClass + " li.errorList").remove();`

Comment: You could use .hide() to remove the li

Comment: @Pooshonk `hide()` hides it, `remove()` removes it from the DOM. It was specified that it should be removed.

Comment: Never heard of .hasClass before, thanks for the help and all the quick responses. It works :)

Answer (score 1):

This could help

```
var test = document.getElementById('test') //returns a HTML DOM Object
var test = $('#test') //returns a jQuery Object
var test = $('#test')[0] //returns a HTML DOM Object
```

So you can use `if($('#test')[0])` to check if the element exists in the DOM.

Example also to check if the element has a class

```
if($('#test')[0] && $('#test').hasClass("test")) {
    $('#test').removeClass("test");
}
```

Comment: Theoretical -1 for Jarvan.

Comment: Yes :) Demacia, Now and Forever! :)